# Review History Time Machine

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-history

The review history time machine (not a real thing) cannot go back to the beginning of time.

As of today, the review history dates back as followed:

Stack Overflow
[image]

- [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/100000) ~ *100000*.
- [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12477419) ~ *12477419*.
- [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12476463) ~ *12476463*.
- [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1247756) ~ *1247756*.
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12478079) ~ *12478079*.
- [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12478035) ~ *12478035*.
- [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4822351) ~ *4822351*.
- [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12478117) ~ *12478117*.

Meta
[image]

- [Close Votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/9557) ~ *9557*.
- [Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9549) ~ *9549*.
- [Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/?) ~ *?*.

Any ID lower than the ones specified above doesn't exist in the Stack Exchange universe. With questions, you can go back to the beginning of time by requesting [question with ID `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) (ergo, the first post).

My hypothesis as to why the time machine cannot go further back in time is because of a fracture in the time data. It is simply because the Stack Exchange universe is expanding too fast, and because of this, the time data is ripped out of existence (old review history gets deleted with time).

Are there any inhabitants of the meta planet who knows why you can't go further back than the IDs specified above (e.g by requesting [review with ID `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1))?

Comment: ... what are you talking about? It's really unclear what you're trying to ask. "question not found" just means the question has subsequently been deleted.

Comment: [Close ~ 100000](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqlX.png) ... works as designed.

Comment: The lowest I could find for close on main was [82279](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/82279) -- lower than that seem to give 404's.

Comment: Actually... the review id's combined in all the reviews, so trying to use an id that's for a suggested edit will 404 in close votes. that makes sense. I'm an idiot.

Comment: Trying to go back further than what's specified in my list isn't possible. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1247755

Comment: But it clearly is, both @rene and I have provided examples.

Comment: For example, suggest edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/82156

Comment: Here's a query that shows you the currently visible lowest id's for different review types on SO: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490892/review-types-count-first-review-id

Comment: Just get to 10K and have access to all review history

Comment: If you've got the free time to try and reverse engineer the Id mechanism, you have time to edit/review some posts... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review task Id's are shared amongst reviews. When you encounter a 404 looking at a review queue, it's probably because the Id you've entered is for a different queue type.

You can see what review type a review task has with:

```
select * from ReviewTasks rt 
inner join ReviewTaskTypes rtt on rt.ReviewTaskTypeId = rtt.Id
where rt.Id = -- put review task id here
```

You can also see the first review Ids for each query [this query that I made](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490892/review-types-count-first-review-id).

```
select rtt.Id, rtt.Name, count(rt.Id) as Number, min(rt.Id) as FirstId, min(rt.CreationDate) as First from
ReviewTasks rt
inner join ReviewTaskTypes rtt on rt.ReviewTaskTypeId = rtt.Id
group by rtt.Id, rtt.Name
order by 1
```

The first review on SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1) in the LQP queue. You'll notice the ID is 1.

Comment: What happened to the query list?

Comment: @Alek what do you mean?

Comment: Never mind. Works again.